# How to get the real path name of a file - currently getting a fakepath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

When I select a file and try to upload it to the server, the path of the local file appears to be as 
   `C:\\\\fakepath\\filename.png` .

I understand that this is a security feature browsers have adapted, but the How can I get the real path in-order to upload the file from my `node.js` method ?

HTML

```
    <input type="file" name="file"  id="pdffile" />
    <a id="showHidden" class="btn btn-warning">button</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#click').click(function(){

        var data = {};
                data.title = $('#subfile').val();
                data.message = "message";

        $.ajax({
          url: "/fillll/path",
          type:'post',
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
          context: document.body
        });
    });
```

Note: I have seen many post on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38596157/stripe-fileuploader-in-meteor-js-gives-error-for-the-fakepath), however i couldn't still solve my problem.

Comment: You can't, that's the entire point, it's a security measure !

Comment: does this appear on console or DB

Comment: If you want to upload the file, you're missing [some settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously#answer-8758614), but you still won't get the real path.

Comment: Ok, then how can I solve this ?